# can you please explain the behaviour of property of this object in these different cases

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

let consider i have  a object 'msg' i re-define it in following cases but i am not understand the behaviour of its property (specially m1). why it is undefined inside the object and it is give string value when i access it through function (last case). can you explain for each case

```
case 0
    var msg = {
    m1 : "this is string",
    m2 : "ok, " + this.m1

};

console.log(msg.m1); //this is string
console.log(msg.m2); // ok, undefined
/////// why m1 is undefined inside msg
//------------------------------------------
case 1
var msg1 = new Object(msg);

console.log(msg1.m1); //this is string
console.log(msg1.m2); // ok, undefined
//again undefined

//------------------------------------------
case 2
var msg2 = {
    m1 : function () { return "this is string";},
    m2 : "ok, " + this.m1,
    m3 : typeof this.m1

};

console.log(msg2.m1()); //this is string
console.log(msg2.m2); // ok, undefined
console.log(msg2.m3); // undefined
console.log(typeof msg2.m1) // function  'but inside msg2 it is undefined why'

//------------------------------------------
case 3
var msg3 = {
    m1 : (function () { return "this is string";}()),
    m2 : "ok, " + this.m1,
    m3 : typeof this.m1
};
console.log(msg3.m1); //this is string
console.log(msg3.m2); // ok, undefined
console.log(msg3.m3); // undefined
console.log(typeof msg3.m1) // string (atleast i know why this is )  but inside msg2 it is not defined (why )

//------------------------------------------
case 4
var msg4 = {
    m1 : (function () { return "this is string";}()),
    m2 : function () { return "ok, " + this.m1; },
    m3 : typeof this.m1
};
console.log(msg4.m1); //this is string
console.log(msg4.m2()); // ok, this is string 
console.log(msg4.m3); // undefined
console.log(typeof msg4.m1) // string (atleast i know why this is )  but inside msg2 it is not defined and in m2 it evaluated (why so)
```

Comment: what happens if you try `m2 : "ok, " += this.m1`

Comment: @RASG: A ReferenceError.  `+=` on a string literal?  That ain't gonna work.  The left side of `+=` has to be an lvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` will never refer to the object that is currently being made via object literal syntax.

`this` refers to the environment's calling context. Objects themselves don't have a calling context, but they can be used *as* a calling context.

Notice your `msg4.m2()` works. That's because `this` is the calling context of the function, and a reference to the object on which the method was invoked, which is the `msg4` object.

How did `msg4` become the calling context of the `m2` function? It's because when you do this:

```
msg4.m2();
```

you are invoking `m2` *on* the `msg4` object. This automatically sets up the calling context so that `this` points to the `msg4` object.

Comment: ok you mean i can't use one property of object to evaluate the other like `container:$('#container')` then no direct way to use `container`  for `imgs: container.find('img')` and i really not understand second part (is there any easy way to understand this concept )

Comment: @NatwarSingh: Not while the object is being constructed. You first need a reference to an existing object, whether via a variable, or via `this`. You updated your comment. Just a second...

Comment: @NatwarSingh: With your `container` example, you would first need to define the object. You can add the `container` property while you define it. But to reference the object when setting the `imgs` property, you'll need to do it after the object has been created, like `myobject.imgs = container.find("img")`

Comment: now i got it but the main problem (this) is really difficult to understand from this 'Objects themselves don't have a calling context, but they can be used as a calling context.'

Comment: @NatwarSingh: Only functions have a calling context. What that means is that the value of `this` only changes inside a function. It doesn't change when you define an object using object literal syntax. That's why `{foo: "foo", bar: this.foo}` doesn't work. `this` will be a reference to whatever the function *(or global)* context is, but it will never be a reference to the object when you use that syntax.

Comment: ...`this` is very dynamic. It can be set a number of different ways, but it is *only* set when calling a function *(aside from the global)*. It is bound to the function call, not to any other structure. For example, `this` will never change inside an `if` statement. `alert(this); if (true) { alert(this); }` The two alerts will have the same `this` value.

Comment: yeah  `this` is really tricky. from you last and second last comment, only function can change scope  and if your object defined inside a function for e.g. in `func` then `this.foo` try to excess the property of `func` not the `object`. am i right here.

Comment: and in my 4th case function change the scope so `this.m1` accessed in the scope of `msg` and evaluated as  `msg.m1` and  give correct result but for case 3rd it is like `window.m1` (is it right)

Comment: @Natwarsingh: Sorry, I got pulled away. Yes, the value of `this` is based on how you call a function. There are several ways you can call a function that can result in a different `this` value. So the `this` value isn't directly related to the function itself, but rather is related to how you invoked the function. It's a strange concept, but makes sense once you get accustomed to it.